# Can't remove or install kerio-control-vpnclient

Tags: apt, 18.04, dpkg

I had installed "kerio-control-vpnclient" in a lower version since i downloaded and tried to upgrade to a newer version ( 9.0 to 9.2 ) i got into this trouble . i can neither install or remove it now !
this is output of sudo dpkg --configure kerio-control-vpnclient

```
    Setting up kerio-control-vpnclient (9.2.7.2921-1) ...
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
Failed to start kerio-kvc.service: Unit kerio-kvc.service is not loaded properly: Exec format error.
See system logs and 'systemctl status kerio-kvc.service' for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript kerio-kvc, action "start" failed.
● kerio-kvc.service - Kerio Control VPN Client
   Loaded: error (Reason: Exec format error)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Oct 04 22:03:24 agha-Satellite-P755 systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/kerio-kvc.service:13: Executable path is not absolute: pkill -SIGHUP kvpncsvc
Oct 04 22:03:33 agha-Satellite-P755 systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/kerio-kvc.service:13: Executable path is not absolute: pkill -SIGHUP kvpncsvc
Oct 04 22:03:33 agha-Satellite-P755 systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/kerio-kvc.service:13: Executable path is not absolute: pkill -SIGHUP kvpncsvc
Oct 04 22:03:33 agha-Satellite-P755 systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/kerio-kvc.service:13: Executable path is not absolute: pkill -SIGHUP kvpncsvc
Oct 04 22:03:53 agha-Satellite-P755 systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/kerio-kvc.service:13: Executable path is not absolute: pkill -SIGHUP kvpncsvc
Oct 04 22:03:53 agha-Satellite-P755 systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/kerio-kvc.service:13: Executable path is not absolute: pkill -SIGHUP kvpncsvc
Oct 04 22:03:53 agha-Satellite-P755 systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/kerio-kvc.service:13: Executable path is not absolute: pkill -SIGHUP kvpncsvc
Oct 04 22:05:54 agha-Satellite-P755 systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/kerio-kvc.service:13: Executable path is not absolute: pkill -SIGHUP kvpncsvc
Oct 04 22:05:54 agha-Satellite-P755 systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/kerio-kvc.service:13: Executable path is not absolute: pkill -SIGHUP kvpncsvc
Oct 04 22:05:54 agha-Satellite-P755 systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/kerio-kvc.service:13: Executable path is not absolute: pkill -SIGHUP kvpncsvc
dpkg: error processing package kerio-control-vpnclient (--configure):
 installed kerio-control-vpnclient package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 kerio-control-vpnclient
```

this is output of apt-get install -f

```
E: The package kerio-control-vpnclient needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

Comment: did you managed to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is my first run with `pkill` to find my system's path for `pkill`, then edit your `/lib/systemd/system/kerio-kvc.service` and use the full path on `ExecReload` for `pkill`.

At the end it should look like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Kerio Control VPN Client
After=network.target
[Service]
Type=forking
Restart=always
RestartSec=5
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/kvpncsvc /var/lib/kerio-control-vpn 2>&1 | logger -p daemon.err -t kerio-control-vpnclient 2>/dev/null
ExecReload=/usr/bin/pkill -SIGHUP kvpncsvc
[Install]
Alias=kerio-vpn
Alias=kerio-control-vpn
Alias=kerio-control-vpnclient
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```